# testing angular template driven forms

Tags: angular, forms, jasmine, angular-forms, angular-test

I am using angular 5, always the `.controls` property of the form is empty.  Not sure why during testing angular doesn't create the form controls by reading the template file.

Template file

```
<form 
  #myForm="ngForm"
  novalidate>
  <input 
    #myCtrl
    required
    type="input" 
    name="myCtrl" 
    id="myCtrl"
    [(ngModel)]="value">
</form>
```

Component file

`@ViewChild('myForm') myForm: NgForm;`

In my tests, when I console.log the following, I get `{}`

`fixture.debugElement.componentInstance.myForm.controls`

The form also has errors: `null` and status `VALID` despite the fact that the form should contain an invalid `FormControl`. Is it possible to unit test forms when they are configured with `ViewChild` rather than `FormBuilder`? Is there a way to do it with my `ViewChild` setup?

or do we have to mock the form by creating the controls again using FormGroup and assign it to

`componentInstance.myForm.controls`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was missing async in `beforeEach()`, though I had the `testbed` configuration in `async`.

Also use `@ViewChild('nameOfForm') sampleForm: NgForm`;

while the test runs the spec, the form controls specified in the template does gets initialized and available in `component.sampleForm`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put fixture.detectChanges() prior to checking for the controls.